# coreservicesd/lssave keeps writing every 30s

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Yesterday I notice that some thing kept writing with 1.48M/s bursting speed every 30s via activity monitor.
Then I close all the unnecessary processes, it was still there. I switched user, which didn't make sense either. Then I did some searching and learned to use iotop to monitor.

It shows that a process called "lssave" writes a lot every 30s with different PID each time. But they share the same PPID, this time the PPID is [28]. I use ps -ef to look up, the PID 28 guy is /System/Library/CoreServices/coreservicesd.

I cannot make any progress because when searching about this guy, all the results are about some irrelevant stuff.

My Mac Lion version is 10.7.3. Free memory is more then 5G. It does matter because I want to switch to SSD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solved. link: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-113924.html

execute:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Comment: Please accept your answer using the tick on the left hand side, rather than just adding "solved" to your answer - This will prevent others coming here to solve your problem. That said, thanks for taking the time to post your solution. +1